# Could Power BI be causing an Access database to corrupt?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-powerbi

I've recently started using Power BI Desktop and have been creating a report pulling data from an Access database. Since starting on the report the Access database has required repairing on 3 occasions (in the past 2 weeks). I can't decide if this is a coincidence or not. I have tried searching for similar issues and have only found cases where reports in Power BI become corrupt after changes in Access, not the other way round. Any help would be appreciated.